# Nested touchables in react native event propagation not working

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablewithoutfeedback

I have a TouchableWithoutFeedback (child) with an onLongPress method inside a TouchableOpacity (parent) with an onPress method.

What I want is that a regular press (not long press) on the child component should trigger the onPress method of the parent. My long press works correctly at the moment but a regular press does not propagate up to the parent TouchableOpacity.

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance.